# Not getting every transaction and unable to parse data

Tags: ethers.js, abi, pancakeswap, websocket, quicknode

The following JS code uses a basic `BNB Smart Chain` endpoint from `QuickNode` and `ethers.js v6.3.0` to parse all transactions' data that is sent to `PancakeSwap` address.

```
const address = '0x18B2A687610328590Bc8F2e5fEdDe3b582A49cdA';
const interface = new ethers.Interface(abi);

provider.on("pending", async (tx) => {
    const txInfo = await provider.getTransaction(tx);

    if (txInfo !== null && txInfo['to'] === address) {
      let decodedData = interface.parseTransaction({ data: txInfo.data });
```

However there are two issues related to the execution:

1. The provider does not deliver all transactions to `PancakeSwap`. I have verified this by sending a transaction on my own to `PancakeSwap` address. My only guess is that this could be a premium feature of `QuickNode` which is not available in the basic free version.
2. The `ethers.js` interface does not always parse the transaction's data. In most cases, the execution of `parseTransaction` function returns `null`.

Additionally, this is the ABI used to get the interface

```
const abi = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_oracleAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBear","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"BetBull","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Claim","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"roundId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"EndRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"roundId","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"int256","name":"price","type":"int256"}],"name":"LockRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"admin","type":"address"}],"name":"NewAdminAddress","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewBufferAndIntervalSeconds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewMinBetAmount","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"NewOperatorAddress","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"oracle","type":"address"}],"name":"NewOracle","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewOracleUpdateAllowance","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"NewTreasuryFee","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"previousOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"OwnershipTransferred","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Paused","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"treasuryAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"RewardsCalculated","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"StartRound","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TokenRecovery","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"TreasuryClaim","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"account","type":"address"}],"name":"Unpaused","type":"event"},{"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_TREASURY_FEE","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"adminAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"betBear","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"}],"name":"betBull","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"bufferSeconds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"epochs","type":"uint256[]"}],"name":"claim","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"claimTreasury","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"claimable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"currentEpoch","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"executeRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisLockRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartOnce","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"genesisStartRound","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"cursor","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"size","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getUserRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256[]","name":"","type":"uint256[]"},{"components":[{"internalType":"enum PancakePredictionV2.Position","name":"position","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"claimed","type":"bool"}],"internalType":"struct PancakePredictionV2.BetInfo[]","name":"","type":"tuple[]"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"getUserRoundsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"intervalSeconds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"ledger","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum PancakePredictionV2.Position","name":"position","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"claimed","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"minBetAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"operatorAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracle","outputs":[{"internalType":"contract AggregatorV3Interface","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleLatestRoundId","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"oracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_token","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"recoverToken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"address","name":"user","type":"address"}],"name":"refundable","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"renounceOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"rounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"epoch","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"startTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lockTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"closeTimestamp","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"lockPrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"int256","name":"closePrice","type":"int256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"lockOracleId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"closeOracleId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"totalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bullAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"bearAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardBaseCalAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"rewardAmount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"oracleCalled","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_adminAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setAdmin","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_bufferSeconds","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_intervalSeconds","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setBufferAndIntervalSeconds","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_minBetAmount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setMinBetAmount","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_operatorAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"setOperator","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_oracle","type":"address"}],"name":"setOracle","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_oracleUpdateAllowance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setOracleUpdateAllowance","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_treasuryFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setTreasuryFee","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryAmount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"treasuryFee","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"userRounds","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]
```

Any directions would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.